# Displaying userIDs for system processes in bash

Tags: bash

I need to create a list of userIDs that are running process on a system regardless of if they are logged on or not. However I'm having a problem display the full user name, here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

top -n 1 | while read line
do
    if [ $i -ge 7 ]
    then
        check=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
        if [ $check != "root" ]
        then
            user=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
            echo $user
        fi
    fi

    i=$((i+1))
done
```

The top command is only printing out the first 8 characters of a user name. Is there a variation of top that will give me the full userID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line:

```
ps -eo uid= | tr -d ' ' | grep -vx 0 | sort | uniq
```

The steps are:

- Print UIDs of all running processes
- Trim whitespace (since `ps` right-justifies the numbers)
- Remove any lines that say 0 (e.g. the root user)
- Sort the remaining lines so that duplicates are grouped together
- Remove adjacent duplicates

If you want to show user names instead of UID numbers:

```
ps -eo user= | grep -vx root | sort | uniq
```

As mentioned in a comment below,  you can specify `ruid` or `ruser` instead of `uid` or `user`, if you want the processes' "real" (rather than "effective") UIDs or usernames.  (If you run a setuid program, the "effective" user is the owner of the program, but the "real" user is still you.)

Also, you can add `-c` to the `uniq` command to get a count of how *many* processes each user owns.  You can even sort again by number of processes:

```
ps -eo user= | grep -vx root | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: ps -eo ruser= if want the name instead of the UID.

Comment: Wow. This is great. I'm getting some extra users tho

Comment: What makes a user "extra" if you're looking for all users who are running anything on the system?

Comment: Yea nevermind. I thought there was duplicates but it works good